# How to make single zip which installs on joomla 1.5, joomla2.5 and joomla3.0

Tags: joomla

I am very frustrated.
I did not get any of document regarding how to make single zip file for Each version of Joomla.

I want to keep my component in single zip file which install on any joomla version that is 1.5,2.5 and 3.0 as well.

Please help

Thx..

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid packages for all versions. But if you really want to have a single package, you kind find more informations on [Joomla! Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Making_single_installation_packages_for_Joomla!_1.5_and_2.5_series).